# What type of streaming protocols and sockets to use for live video streaming

Tags: c++, html, tcp, stream, udp

I am a building a video server written in C++ to stream live video to a web video client written in php and html to implement video chatting.

What type of protocols eg. "UDP,TCP, RTP, RTSP, MMS, blocking, non-blocking" should i use to stream the live and constantly changing video to to my web client.

I have tried to stream video using non-blocking socket using TCP protocol but the video stops after playing the first clip streamed, it does not continue to play the clips proceedingly streamed.

An example i know is using Windows Media Encoder to stream the content from your webcam and access it using your browser with just a simple embed  tag like this:

```
<object ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" CLASSID="CLSID:22D6f312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject" CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112">
<param name="autoStart" value="True">
<param name="filename" value="http://127.0.0.1:8888">
<param NAME="ShowControls" VALUE="False">
<param NAME="ShowStatusBar" VALUE="False">
<embed TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" SRC="http://127.0.0.1:8888" NAME="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" autostart="1" showcontrols="0"></embed></object>
```

I also like to know what type of streaming protocol does Windows Media Encoder use to achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

There are protocols dedicated to video streaming.... You should read about RTP and HTTP Live Streaming to begin with.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am developing the video server application for Windows. Does Windows support HTTP live Streaming ? Are there any links to tutorials on implementing RTP or HTTP live Streaming on Windows using C++ ?

Comment: Of course it supports it, VLC implements both of them, you can just grab it from there.